# find the word in a multi-stage internet scavenger hunt

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, cipher, computer-puzzle

The answer can be anything.
For you can search a lifetime.
To discover the bookmarked answer.
You *m*ust traverse *d*own the long long walls.
*Using the number of walls of each frame.*
The key hides twice in its last name.

hint 1:

> you find the answer quite literally outside of this box.

hint 2:

> the word is hidden

hint 3:

> italics are key

hint 4:

> the key hides twice in its last name. how do you hide passwords?

IMPORTANT PSA:

> As you solve the puzzle you may come across "congratulations, you solved the puzzle". If thats all you see, you did something wrong and you didn't actually solve the puzzle correctly. IT HAS NOT HOLD SIGINIFICANCE AT ALL IN THE PUZZLE PLEASE DO NOT SPEND TIME ON IT. Happy solving!

Comment: Since the puzzle isn't solved yet this feedback may not be valid.  However it seems like you have an interesting puzzle, but it may need more cluing to be reasonably solvable.  I *think* that between myself and some previous answers I have a partial solution but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for knowing if I am on the right track.  For multipart puzzles it helps a lot when you get positive feedback after solving each part so you know you are on the right track rather than only knowing if you were correct when you get to the end.

Comment: @Barker since this is multipart, once you get to the next part there will definitely know you will be on the right track.

Comment: It might be time for another hint.

Answer (score 3):

PARTIAL ANSWER:

> Per the hint given in the comment under David G.'s answer, we look for a book from Jorge Luis Borges
>
>  This leads us to the [Library of Babel](https://libraryofbabel.info/) which does match up with the rest of the puzzle
>
>  "The answer can be anything. For you can search a lifetime. To discover the bookmarked answer." definitely makes sense here. Not sure about the rest of the puzzle though.
>
>  OP did say it was a scavenger hunt.

Comment: rot13(Gur "ybat ybat jnyyf" bs gur bayvar yvoenel pna or genirefrq "qbja" 1000 ng n gvzr (znlor 'jnyyf bs rnpu senzr' ba gung fvgr). V fcbenqvpnyyl qht guebhtu n ovg, fgvyy abg fher jurer gb urnq nsgre gur svefg cntr gubhtu. Guvaxvat znlor 'o' vf gur xrl nf vg "uvqrf gjvpr va vgf ynfg anzr" (yvoenel bs onory))

Comment: rot13(Whfg qvq fbzr erfrnepu vagb gur yvoenel bs onory, gheaf bhg gurl unir n [obbxznex](https://libraryofbabel.info/bookmark.cgi?example) srngher. Abg fher rknpgyl ubj gung eryngrf gb gur chmmyr be vs vg qbrf ng nyy ohg gur evqqyr qbrf zragvba obbxznexf.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure rot13(gur "urk anzr" vf `zq` nf gurfr gjb yrggref nccrne va vgnyvpf va gur evqqyr.)  I have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: @Barker late but just saw this, rota3(lbh zragvbarq urk juvpu erzvaqrq zr bs zq6, n unfu nytbevguz. pbhyq gung or vg?)

Comment: @Barker rot13("uvqvat va vgf ynfg anzr" v gevrq hfvat zq6 gb unfu "Onory" gb trg "qr69311rp534qq8192q692p2qq4933o3ss30o880n0pr117105r4p9n00663srop". ragrerq vg vagb gur obbxznex ohg hasbeghangryl abguvat.)

Comment: @OliverNi hey, im glad you are spending time solving my puzzle! before you proceed further please read my PSA -- again, the PSA message is NOT part of the puzzle.

Comment: rot13(Jura V fnvq "Urk anzr" V jnf ersreevat gb vs lbh tb gb gur Yvoenel bs Onory jrofvgr naq pyvpx "Oebjfr" gur svefg guvat gurl nfx sbe vf gur "Urk anzr" juvpu npprcgf n gjb yrggre vachg.)

Comment: @OliverNi is getting close...

Comment: @KyleHe what is a PSA?

Answer (score 2):

> Home

The answer can be anything.

> home can be anything, as long as it is yours.

For you can search a lifetime.

> A true home can be hard to find

To discover the bookmarked answer.

> In a web browser, home is a variant of a bookmark

You must traverse down the long long walls.

> If home is an apartment, there tend to be long empty corridors.

Using the number of walls of each frame.

> ???

The key hides twice in its last name.

> ???

And the hint,

> on the upper left, is the word Home

Comment: as a hint:  rot13(ernq gur gntf. lbh znl arrq gb qb n ovg bs qvttvat ohg guvf erdhverf hfr bs na vagrearg pncnoyr pbzchgre. nqqvgvbanyyl lbh znl jnag gb ernq n fgbel ol jevgre Wbetr Yhvf Obetrf.)